# compare string from db to posted string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a db where I want a part of it (a name) not to be duplicated. I'm trying to check if it exist and if so not to save this part, however it is saving regardless if it already exists or not.

code:

```
var reviewSubject = from c in db.Subject select 

c.SubjectName.ToString().ToLower();
var match = reviewSubject.FirstOrDefaultAsync(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Equals(model.sub.SubjectName.ToLower()));
model.rev.Created = DateTime.Now;
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if ((model.sub.SubjectName.ToLower()).Equals(match))
    {
        //Do nothing 
    }
    else
    {
        model.sub.GBU = model.rev.GBU;
        db.Subject.Add(model.sub);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of SubjectName attrbuite ?

Comment: just a string (public string SubjectName , [SubjectName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL)

Comment: Far easier to use `bool match = reviewSubject.Any(x => x == model.sub.SubjectName.ToLower());` and then `if (match) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the [await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) keyword on the result from `reviewSubject.FirstOrDefaultAsync` which returns a `Task<T>`. You are therefore checking if the task is equal to the string, which is false.

The correct usage would be:

```
var match = await reviewSubject.FirstOrDefaultAsync(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Equals(model.sub.SubjectName.ToLower()));`
```

If you don't want to use the [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) method you could use the synchronous one as such:

```
var match = reviewSubject.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Equals(model.sub.SubjectName.ToLower()));`
```